# Parameterizing fixtures issue

Tags: python, selenium, testing, pytest

I need to run tests while authorized to the web page under different user accounts(all of them have different permissions). I've created fixtures for that purpose so I can easily login:

```
@pytest.fixture
def login_user1(selenium, credentials):
    page = LoginPage(selenium)
    page.login(credentials)

@pytest.fixture
def login_user2(selenium, credentials):
    page = LoginPage(selenium)
    page.login(credentials)
```

Also, I created a fixture that can be parametrized into running tests for multiple users with just calling it once.

```
@pytest.fixture
def multiple_users(request):
    request.getfixturevalue(request.param)
```

And final fixture for the test looks like(This version works)

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('multiple_users', [pytest.param('login_user1'),
                                            pytest.param('login_user2',marks=pytest.mark.xfail)
                                                ], indirect=True)
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("multiple_users")
def test_user_permission(self, selenium):
   page = HomePage(selenium)
   ......
```

Now I'm trying to pass a unique value to the test function each time test runs for different users. I tried doing something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('multiple_users,value', [(pytest.param('login_user1'), 'value1'),
                                            (pytest.param('login_user2',marks=pytest.mark.xfail), 'value2')
                                                ], indirect=True)
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("multiple_users")
def test_user_permission(self, selenium, value):
   page = HomePage(selenium)
   ......
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm also considering remaking this system entirely so if there is an overall better way to do something similar let me know.

Comment: You can make `page.login` a part of the test & parametrize that test with various credentials so that login happens inside test with different users.

Comment: @AmitVerma Yes, I was thinking about something like that thx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: So yes, I ended up with moving page login into the tests themselves and getting rid of fixtures login_user1 and login_user2, etc.